# Routes in DART, s server required?

Tags: routes, dart, angular-ui-router, dart-polymer, angular-dart

I tried both AngularDART routes, and routes with Polymer, [this example](http://bwu-dart.github.io/bwu_polymer_routing/example/example_02.html)

but found, that none is working once I open the file from Dartium directly, but both work perfectly once I run them from Dart editor!

am I doing something wrong!

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'open from Dartium directly' and 'run them from Dart editor'.

Comment: Run from Dart editor by Ctrl+R is opening the Dartium and with URL "http://localhost:8082/example_01.html" and everything s fine.

the second way I tried, copy file path, and paste it in Dartium as: "file:///C:/absolutepathtofile/example_01.html" displayed only:
"The examples source code can be found here."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the point is both using "import html" file, which can run with web server and some browsers,, for example route run smoothly at Safari browser without web server, but did not run without server at Chrome, and Chrome shows this error msg:

```
Imported resource from origin 'file://' has been blocked from loading by 
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: Received an invalid response. Origin 'null'
is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: I think when you load this from files directly you need to start Chrome with this argument `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you run from DartEditor (Ctrl+R) `pub serve` is launched which acts as a web server for the browser. This doesn't mean that you need a web server to run this example though.
What makes the difference is that `pub serve` runs transformers that do some sorts of code modification on the fly when the browser requests a page from the server.

When you run `pub build` (or `pub build example` when the code is not in `web` directory) this code modifications (and some more like tree-shaking and minification) are applied and you can open the resulting output (from `build/example/example_01.html`) directly without a server using a file URL.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I was thinking this is required only if I want to run the app in browsers other than DARTIUM, any how I run 'pub build' and got the files generation, but same results :(


I notice a warning msg that I reported [here](https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_polymer_routing/issues/2)

Comment: Dart code **should** run without transformers applied but for example the `di` package depends on running the transformer even when run in Dartium. I tried to open the build output using a file URI and it worked. The example link in your question (I modified it because it was broken) is nothing else then the build output uploaded to GitHub. The only difference is that it doesn't need a file URI but a normal http URI.

Comment: I updated my previous comment. I opened the `example/example_01.html` file instead of the `build/example/example_01.html`. The former resulted in a page only showing the link to the examples. When I opened the correct file it worked fine.

Comment: mmm, I do not know if I'm doing something wrong, nothing changed with me, I got the same issue today while testing AngularDART UI, as I mentioned here: https://plus.google.com/110229866977286723923/posts/UAH8ez51S53

Comment: My routing packages uses the same DI package as AngularDart. (The route_hierarchical package is the same too bit I'm pretty sure this is because the di-Transformer needs to be run).

Comment: mmm, hope I'm not stuck yet, is there a chance that you send me somehow to see if it is running correctly in my PC, there might be something wrong in my PC or in the build process happen here!

Comment: Can you please update the question and explain what exactly you are trying to do. Then I can have a look.